# Equivalent Query Produce Different Result

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I believe the following queries are equivalent and should produce the same result :

```
select CITY from TBL_X
where CITY not in (
  select CITY from TBL_X
  where CITY in (
    select CITY 
    from TBL_Y
  )
)


select CITY 
from TBL_X
where CITY not in (
  select CITY 
  from TBL_Y
);
```

But the first query produce 10 rows of data while the second produce 0 row of data. Is there any logical explanation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `not in` with a subquery.  It returns no rows when *any* value returned by the subquery is `NULL`.

Instead, use `not exists`:

```
select x.CITY 
from TBL_X x
where not exists (select 1
                  from tbl_y y
                  where y.CITY = x.CITY 
                 );
```

Your queries are not equivalent, in the same way that these are not opposites:

```
where x = y
where not (x = y)
```

Both of these clauses filter out `NULL` values.

Comment: `Do not use not` ... that's a double negative, my head is spinning +1